# How to use a KVM switch with newer USB-C / DIsplayPort systems without 3.5mm audio

Tags: displayport, dell-latitude, kvm-switch, usb-c, thunderbolt

I have a challenge. I have a "work from home" setup provided by an employer. I want to add my desktop in a dual setup, with a KVM.

1. They provided a Dell laptop with thunderbolt port.
2. They provided a Dell WD19TBS docking station. It does not provide any 3.5mm audio output. It has 2 display ports, and an HDMI port. From what I've read, audio can be passed through these ports.
3. They provided two monitors. One of the two monitors provided is a U2242HE with a built in USB-C dock and has a 3.5mm line-out connector and no built-in speakers. The other monitor is a basic DisplayPort compatible monitor.

I intended to upgrade the video card on my desktop with a dual display port card, and add a dual displayport KVM switch.

My challenge is that I want to also use external speakers which need a 3.5mm audio jack and have this be part of the KVM setup.

Yet, the WD19TBS dock doesn't have a 3.5mm output. And, I can't use the monitor's USB-C dock with a KVM setup unless somehow I am switching USB-C ports instead because the monitor, of course, acts as a hardwired monitor to the dock.

My problem is this.

1. I need to be able to switch between the work laptop and the desktop with a KVM switch.
2. The KVM switch should switch ALL peripherals, including the audio.
3. I want to use my external speakers which require a 3.5mm jack.
4. I want to use the hardware provided by my employer.
5. I can add whatever hardware is necessary to the desktop.

Does anybody see a path for this?

These new setups only using thunderbolt/usb-c and expectations of passing audio over HDMI / DisplayPort is a pain in the butt.

Comment: Any cheap (as cheap as ~$1 shipping included from AliExpress) USB audio adapter can provide an analog 3.5mm audio output plus a microphone input.

Comment: As long as your dock, your desktops video card and the KVM switch, as well as the monitor are able to router audio over displayport/HDMI it should be as simple as setting the appropriate audio output in your OS.